# Formatting output with printf piped in with xargs

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, text-formatting

I want to search my code base for ocurrences of a string, and then get the formatted output as filename, line number, and code lide. I got it as I wanted on the first line of the output, but the coming lines loses the wanted formatting.

```
$ find src/ -name "*.js" | xargs grep --null -E -n 'filter\(|map\(' | xargs -0 printf "%-100s%-5s%-100s" > test.txt
```

The output is as follows: (scroll right to see the complete line)

```
src/components/AppRouterSwitch.js                                                                   15:    return _Routes.map((route, index) => {
src/components/forms/UserEditForm/UserEditForm.js36:    const options = UserTypes.map((type, index) => <option key={index} value={type.type}>{type.name}</option>);
src/components/pages/AdminPage/SolutionManagementEditPage/SolutionManagementEditPage.js119:        templates:state.templates.filter(item=>item.SOLUTIONID ==id)
src/components/pages/AdminPage/SolutionManagementEditPage/SolutionManagementEditPage.js120:            .map(item=>{return{
```

The first row looks just as I want it. The following loses the desired formatting. Ending the printf format string with `/n` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Try to use the standard option of grep `-l` (a lowercase L)

Comment: @malyy I tried that with some variations but no success. I don't see how the -l option would help me.
  
-l, --files-with-matches
              Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input
              file from which output would normally have been printed.  The
              scanning will stop on the first match.

Comment: please check my answer and clarify if you really want the colon (:) after the line number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find src/ -type f -name '*.js' -exec grep -Hn -E -- 'filter\(|map\(' {} + |
    awk -F: '{printf "%-100s%-5s%-100s\n", $1, $2, substr($0, length($1) + length($2) + 3)}'
```

The `-H` option to `grep` will cause it to print the filename even when called with a single file as argument. The `-type f` option to find is needed in order to skip broken links and directories that happen to be named `*.js`.

Or even simpler, get rid of grep completely (thanks to @don_crissti for the suggestion):

```
find src/ -type f -name '*.js' -exec awk '/filter\(|map\(/{printf "%-100s%-5s%-100s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0}' {} +
```

Comment: Elegant solution, just what I needed. The colon is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`man` makes it a bit unclear. "The scanning will stop on the first match" - indicates that all file names will be printed, but the scanning for the matching word will stop at the first occurence.
[GNU grep man](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) page clarifies this:

```
-l
--files-with-matches
Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed. The scanning of each file stops on the first match. (-l is specified by POSIX.)
```

Here is an example:

```
$grep -iR Intel * 
2018/jan/cpu.txt:Intel i9 
2018/motherboard.txt:Intel Motherboard 
hardware.txt:Intel Corei7
#the same result as you provided;

$grep -iRl Intel * 
2018/jan/cpu.txt
2018/motherboard.txt
hardware.txt
#the desired result
```

Comment: Not quite what I wanted. Please scroll the output to the right and you'll se that I also want line number and line of code, but formatted as on the first row.